# Caesar encryption not returning wanted value

Tags: c, if-statement, char, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am solving pset2s caesar and I've been encountering some bugs and I also couldn't figure out how to check if the given key was an integer or not but I'm guessing its with some type of error control? Anyways this is what I've written so far:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char rotate(char c, int n);

char lower[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
char upper[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);
    string word = get_string("plaintext: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        word[i] = rotate(word[i], key);
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", word);
}

char rotate(char c, int key){
    int location;
    if(isupper(c)){
        location = c - 'A';
        location = location + key % 26;
        c = upper[location];
    }
    else if(islower(c)){
        location = c - 'a';
        location = location + key % 26;
        c = lower[location];
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: If the question is, "How can I determine whether `argv[1]` is or isn't numeric?", the answer is "*Don't* use `atoi()`.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```
int location;
if(isupper(c)){
    location = c - 'A';
    location = location + key % 26;
    c = upper[location];
}
else if(islower(c)){
    location = c - 'a';
    location = location + key % 26;
    c = lower[location];
}
```

is invalid. It seems you mean

```
c = 'A' + ( location + key ) % 26;
```

and

```
c = 'a' + ( location + key ) % 26;
```

or

```
c = upper[ ( location + key ) % 26];
```

and

```
c = lower[( location + key ) % 26];
```

And these statements

```
    c = upper[location];
    c = lower[location];
```

must be removed.

Also it will be more safer to write

```
if(isupper(( unsigned char )c)){
```

and

```
if(islower(( unsigned char )c)){
```

To determine whether the key is specified correctly use the function `strtol` instead of `atoi`.

Comment: I figured the problem, my code wasn't returning a full word because it was indexing out of the range of the array, thats why I got a segmentation error. Fixed it now thanks!